# Fourier Transform existence

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Moreover, consider that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a schwarzian function, i.e. $f\in C^{\infty}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty} |x^n f^{(m)}(x)|=0,\ \forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. (they are called rapidly decreasing function). Is it true that the following integral exists?

$$\widehat{f}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{i\varphi (x,t)}dt $$

Comment: Yes, it exists for any $f \in L^1$, since $|e^{i \varphi (x,t)}| \equiv 1$.

Comment: I know that but this is not the case...

Comment: $f$ is obviously $L^1$, as it is continuous, hence $L^1_{loc}$, and $f =o(\frac{1}{x^2})$ at infinity, so integrable at infinity

Answer (score 0):

Since $\varphi$ is real valued $|e^{i\varphi(x,t)}|=1$ and
$$
\Bigl|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\,e^{i\varphi (x,t)}\,dt \Bigr|\le\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|\,dt=\|f\|_1.
$$
For the existence of the integral it is ehough that $f\in L^1$.

Comment: But how do you prove in practice that $f$ is $L^1$? That is why I assume that $f$ should be schwarzian...

Comment: Any Schwarz function is in $L^1$. For each $n$ there is a constant $C_n$ such that $|f(x)|\le C_n/(1+|x|^n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I though that this is not true for any schwarz function.